# ndarray throws Data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, pandas, series, numpy-ndarray

```
    input_data_ndarray = np.array(
        [['chicken', 'creamofchickensoup'], ['Chicken', 'CreamofChickensoup'], ['chicken', 'creamofchickensoup']])
    result = pd.Series(input_data_ndarray).apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x))).nunique()
```

For the above code, throws

```
raise Exception("Data must be 1-dimensional")
E               Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

Any idea about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could help:

```
In [1959]: pd.Series(input_data_ndarray.tolist())                                                                                                                                                           
Out[1959]: 
0    [chicken, creamofchickensoup]
1    [Chicken, CreamofChickensoup]
2    [chicken, creamofchickensoup]
dtype: object
```

OR if you want a `dataframe`, do this:

```
In [1960]: pd.DataFrame(input_data_ndarray)                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[1960]: 
         0                   1
0  chicken  creamofchickensoup
1  Chicken  CreamofChickensoup
2  chicken  creamofchickensoup
```

Comment: So it converts ndarray to a list of list.Then, apply sort operation. Lastly, get unique count. Right?